# Where does FileHistory save backups when the backup drive isn't present?

Tags: windows-8, file-history

[image: File History: Reconnect your Drive: Your files will be temporarily copied to your hard drive until you reconnect your File History drive and run a backup.]

Where is this folder? On my backup drive it's just `B:\FileHistory` but nothing on the local drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is surprisingly little technical info out there, and nothing from Microsoft at this point regarding this info. However, according to [*Windows 8 – File History Feature replaces “Previous Versions” and Backup and Restore*](http://www.verboon.info/index.php/2012/04/windows-8-file-history-feature-replaces-previous-versions-and-backup-and-restore/), if you:

1. Look at `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\fhsvc\Parameters\Configs`, you should find an entry for each local user who has enabled File History pointing to a configuration path. (The path will look like `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\Config`)
2. In this location, you should find two identical files, `config1.xml` `config2.xml`. Open either one and look for the StagingAreaPath value, which will be similar to `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Data`. This is where your files are stored while your `Target` is unavailable.

Also see the other values under `StagingArea` for maximum cache size.